# Position sticky with submenu not scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap v-4 beta2 and I want to create sticky top menu with submenu. Everything is working on desktop but when on mobile when I click to open submenu I cant see whole submenu and when I am scrolling with whole website but not menu. I found out I have to do something with li.dropdown - when I added position absolute it got a bit messy but I saw the menu. But I cant get what I should do. Here is the code:

```css
li.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

li.dropdown {
  position: static;
}

.multi-columns {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper sticky-top">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light text-uppercase">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Domov <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="eshop.html">E-shop</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu multi-columns">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3 class="h5">Blog</h3>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3 class="h5">Blog 2</h3>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3 class="h5">Blog 3</h3>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h3 class="h5">Blog 4</h3>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form action="" class="form-inline">
          <select class="select2 form-control" style="width: 100%;">
    
              </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /.nav -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.nav-wrapper -->
```

Also when on desktop when I hover on the "dropdown" it gets shown but by the time I get the mouse on the submenu it disapears. Should I move the submenu with margin-top: -10px or smh like that? Or is there any solution?

**Edit**

The main thing is the submenu is greater than viewport and then I simply cant scroll on that

Comment: Is it `position: sticky` or `position: fixed`? These are two different positioning properties and a distinction should be made between them for the sake of clarity. It also looks like your question could do with more style rules to accurately reproduce the problem as a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your sub-menu want to scroll inside the content, for that you need to specify the `max-height` and `overflow: scroll;`.

You also need to change `col-md-3` to `col-lg-3` inside the `dropdown-menu multi-columns` division.

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
.multi-columns{
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
     }
  }
```

**Demo Snippet:**

```css
li.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

li.dropdown {
  position: static;
}

.multi-columns {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
.multi-columns{
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
     }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="nav-wrapper sticky-top">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light text-uppercase">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Domov <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="eshop.html">E-shop</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu multi-columns">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <h3 class="h5">Blog</h3>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <h3 class="h5">Blog 2</h3>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <h3 class="h5">Blog 3</h3>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <h3 class="h5">Blog 4</h3>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form action="" class="form-inline">
          <select class="select2 form-control" style="width: 100%;">
    
              </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /.nav -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.nav-wrapper -->
```

Hope this may help you. [Codepen demo link.](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/aVZyGN)
Thanks.

Comment: thanks, took me a while till I got the chance to test it but its working :) Enjoy your reward :D

Comment: Thanks for your rewards man. In case, if you face any Issues please let me know :).

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/ard5rg6f/1/

I have used few lines of jQuery to add class to sticky div when menu opens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#navbarNav').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
                $('.nav-wrapper.sticky-top').addClass('menu-opened');
            });
            $('#navbarNav').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
                $('.nav-wrapper.sticky-top').removeClass('menu-opened');
            });
        });
```

and removed position absolute property of dropdown menu and added scroll to sticky div.

```
.nav-wrapper.sticky-top {
            position: fixed;
        }
        .nav-wrapper.sticky-top.menu-opened {
            overflow: scroll;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
            position: inherit;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting the nav burger button to 'stick' on the site when you scroll, you will need to position it as fixed.

**Edit:** I forgot the submenu but in chrome devtools enabling mobile mode, this works fine. Clicking the submenu opens up the menu and then clicking on it again, closes it.

```css
li.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

li.dropdown {
  position: static;
}

.multi-columns {
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.nav-wrapper.sticky-top {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-wrapper sticky-top">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light text-uppercase">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Domov <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="eshop.html">E-shop</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu multi-columns">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <h3 class="h5">Blog</h3>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <h3 class="h5">Blog 2</h3>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <h3 class="h5">Blog 3</h3>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <h3 class="h5">Blog 4</h3>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form action="" class="form-inline">
              <select class="select2 form-control" style="width: 100%;">

          </select>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.nav -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav-wrapper -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trouble with fixed is it will crop if the menu is longer than the devices screen height.

Comment: I can open it but I cannot scroll to view the submenu